# Firebase Project - Robot Verification while OTP Authentication

Tags: firebase

I have recently created a new flutter project and added firebase into it.
I am using OTP Verification. However I am getting the "robot verification" step before I can receive the OTP. Can you help me with steps that I need to follow to disable it?

I have enabled the Google Play Integrity API for my firebase Project and I have also added SHA-1 and SHA-256 certificates.

Comment: The robot verification is known as a reCAPTCHA, so have a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+otp+recaptcha to learn about why it is shown and more questions around how to prevent that.